# Creating and submitting a form in tiptip

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tooltip

I just implemented tiptip and found it fantastic to use. Now i want to make a form and use it in tiptip tool tip so that user can fill and submit it.

I have created tiptip as

```
  $('.div').tipTip({
    maxWidth: 1000,
    defaultPosition: 'right',
    content: function (e) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'tets.php', 
        datatype: JSON,
        success: function (response) {
        $('#tiptip_content').html(response);
        $('body').append(response).fadeIn('1000');// the var e is the callback function data (see above)
        }
      });
      return 'Please wait...'; // We temporary show a Please wait text until the ajax success callback is called.
    }
  });
```

I get a form in my tooltip. Now as soon as i take my mouse in it, it disappears (obviously, its a tooltip at the end). Is there any way to do what i am trying to achieve??

My html

```
<div class="div">Hover on Me</div>
```

tets.php

```
<form id = "testForm" method="post" action="newEmptyPHP.php">
  <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="150">Username</td>
      <td width="250"><input name="username" type="text" class="textfield" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Password</td>
      <td><input name="password" type="password" class="textfield" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input name="remember" type="checkbox" value="d"> Remember me</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and explain your issue?

Comment: I can't see any `<form>` there

Comment: How can i include external js library which i downloaded? also the other php file which i use to handle AJAX request?

Comment: @Alexander Form is the response of AJAX call

Comment: Care explaining Down vote, Downvoter?

Comment: @SankalpMishra, why don't you use the `keepAlive` option of TipTip?

Comment: @Alexander When i use that, It removes the form and tooltip, only an arrow is left

Comment: @SankalpMishra There is **Resources** on the left side bar. Please make use of it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Actually i have downloaded the js, it does not provide a link

Comment: Oh okay. You can get it from the Demo page right? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin

"keepAlive: true of false (false by default) - When set to true the TipTip will only fadeout when you hover over the actual TipTip and then hover off of it."

Try adding this property and set it to true

**Update:**

Example here: http://jsbin.com/imeqes/2/

Appears to work fine when you hover over image, then hover over tip, it stays there.

Comment: When i use that, It removes the form and tooltip, only an arrow is left

Comment: hmm..well i've updated my answer with a working example. It might be the ajax get causing it to fail.